# Java HashSet doesn't add two objets with same hashCode and equals (OK) but contains() says second object is not in set

Tags: java, equals, hashset, hashcode

I have a test for testing that adding the same Edge (Arista) but with the same vertices (but flipped order) is the same (this is not a directed graph).

And this is strange because the two first assertions passes OK (adding `Edge1` and `Edge2` will result in `edges.sizes = 1` because they are the same, theoretically).

But then when testing that `edges.contains(Edge2)` returns `false`.

Why could it have worked when testing addition (to not add it duplicated) but does not work when testing `contains()`?

This is the code:

```
    @Test
public final void testAristaWithSameVerticesIsNotAddedTwice() throws Exception {
    Grafo grafo = new Grafo();
    Vertice vertice1 = new Vertice("Vertice 1");
    Vertice vertice2 = new Vertice("Vertice 2");
    grafo.agregarVertice(vertice1);
    grafo.agregarVertice(vertice2);
    Arista arista = new Arista(vertice1, vertice2, 10);
    Arista arista2 = new Arista(vertice2, vertice1, 10);
    grafo.agregarArista(arista);
    grafo.agregarArista(arista);

    assertEquals(1, grafo.getAristasQuantity());
    assertTrue(grafo.hasArista(arista));
    assertTrue(grafo.hasArista(arista2)); // fails here
}
```

Grafo class:

```
private HashSet<Arista> aristas;

public boolean hasArista(Arista arista) {
    return this.aristas.contains(arista);
}
```

Arista class

```
package entities;

public class Arista {

    protected Vertice vertice1;
    protected Vertice vertice2;
    protected int peso;

    public Arista(Vertice vertice1, Vertice vertice2, int peso) {
        this.vertice1 = vertice1;
        this.vertice2 = vertice2;
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public Vertice getVertice1() {
        return vertice1;
    }

    public Vertice getVertice2() {
        return vertice2;
    }

    public int getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }

    public void setPeso(int peso ) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return vertice1.hashCode() + vertice2.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Arista arista) {
        if (arista == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((arista.getVertice1() == this.vertice1 && arista.getVertice2() == this.vertice2)
            || (arista.getVertice2() == this.vertice1 && arista.getVertice1() == this.vertice2)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the `equals()` wasn't overriding the parent definition because it was not well defined. So it wasn't being called.

Correct way is:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Arista) {
        Arista arista = (Arista) object;
        if (arista == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((arista.getVertice1() == this.vertice1 && arista.getVertice2() == this.vertice2)
            || (arista.getVertice2() == this.vertice1 && arista.getVertice1() == this.vertice2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```